# Classification Problem: iterate different K for KNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on a classification problem (tweet sentiment analysis) and I would like to include a `for` loop for different K-values (KNN) in the classifiers list below.

I know that I could just go with:
`KNeighborsClassifier(3), KNeighborsClassifier(5)`... But I am trying to implement the rather elegant solution with a `for` loop.

Unfortunately, trying to create an empty `list` and add the different K values to it and then including it in the `classifiers = []` list does not work properly. Do you have any good recommendations?

My code:

```
classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(3),
    LogisticRegression(),
    SVC(kernel = "rbf", C = 0.025, probability = True),
    NuSVC(probability = True),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    RandomForestClassifier(),
    GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    MultinomialNB(),
    BernoulliNB()] 

for clf in classifiers:
    clf.fit(train_tf, y_train)
    name = clf.__class__.__name__
        
    expectation = y_train
    train_prediction = clf.predict(train_tf)
    acc = accuracy_score(expectation, train_prediction)   
    pre = precision_score(expectation, train_prediction)
    rec = recall_score(expectation, train_prediction)
    f1 = f1_score(expectation, train_prediction)


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(14,4))
    plt.suptitle(f'{name} \n', fontsize = 18)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.8)
    skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(expectation, train_prediction, ax=ax[0])
    skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(expectation, train_prediction, normalize=True, ax = ax[1])
    plt.show()
    
    print(f"for the {name} we receive the following values:")
    print("Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(acc))
    print('Precision score: {:.3%}'.format(pre))
    print('Recall score: {:.3%}'.format(rec))
    print('F1 score: {:.3%}'.format(f1))
```

If you need any more info, just let me know :) Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try it later on and come back if there are any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work, where you basically just freeze the iteration of KNeighbors until all the neighbor values are exhausted.

```
classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(3),
    LogisticRegression(),
    SVC(kernel = "rbf", C = 0.025, probability = True),
    NuSVC(probability = True),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    RandomForestClassifier(),
    GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    MultinomialNB(),
    BernoulliNB()] 
n_neighbors = [3, 5, 6, 10, 15]  # or whatever
class_iter = iter(classifiers)
clf = next(class_iter)
while True:
    try:
        if isinstance(clf, KNeighborsClassifier) and any(n_neighbors):
            neighbor_val = n_neighbors.pop()
            clf.set_params(n_neighbors=neighbor_val)
        else:
            clf = next(class_iter)
        #rest of code here

        clf.fit(train_tf, y_train)
        name = clf.__class__.__name__
            
        expectation = y_train
        train_prediction = clf.predict(train_tf)
        acc = accuracy_score(expectation, train_prediction)   
        pre = precision_score(expectation, train_prediction)
        rec = recall_score(expectation, train_prediction)
        f1 = f1_score(expectation, train_prediction)


        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(14,4))
        plt.suptitle(f'{name} \n', fontsize = 18)
        plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.8)
        skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(expectation, train_prediction, ax=ax[0])
        skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(expectation, train_prediction, normalize=True, ax = ax[1])
        plt.show()
        
        print(f"for the {name} we receive the following values:")
        print("Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(acc))
        print('Precision score: {:.3%}'.format(pre))
        print('Recall score: {:.3%}'.format(rec))
        print('F1 score: {:.3%}'.format(f1))

    except StopIteration:
        break
```